# Replace value in association data-set

Tags: performance-tuning, associations

I have an association dataset with a depth of two (each value is an association too, and the size of the dataset ~ 30000 keys and an average size of values are ~2000 keys association). The dataset looks like:

```
  dataset=<| 2 -> <|3 -> 3, 5 -> 4|>,4 -> <|5 -> 15|>, 5 -> <|1 -> 41, 2 -> 
   4,3 -> 10, 4 -> 11|>|>
```

I need to change specific values in this dataset. I do it in the following manner:

```
dataset= 
 ReplacePart[
   dataset, {Key@23980, Key@19969} -> {5, 
  6}]; // AbsoluteTiming

  {0.000110522, Null}
```

This operation takes a lot of time for my dataset, around 110 msec. I repeat this procedure thousands of times, so it is a real bottleneck for my program.

Any suggestions on how to speed up this procedure?

Here is a working example:

```
dataset = <|2 -> <|3 -> 3, 5 -> 4|>, 4 -> <|5 -> 15|>, 5 -> <|1 -> 41, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 10, 4 -> 11|>|>;
dataset = ReplacePart[dataset, {Key@4, Key@5} -> {5, 6}]
(* <|2 -> <|3 -> 3, 5 -> 4|>, 4 -> <|5 -> 15|>, 5 -> <|1 -> 41, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 10, 4 -> 11|>|> *)
(* <|2 -> <|3 -> 3, 5 -> 4|>, 4 -> <|5 -> {5, 6}|>, 5 -> <|1 -> 41, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 10, 4 -> 11|>|> *)
```

Comment: Can't you just do: `dataset[4, 5] = {5,6}`?

Comment: Thank you!
Yes, so simple so quick, this approach sped up by factor 10. Can you change your comment to answer, please?

Comment: My answer was extra-useless as I wasn't realizing what you are doing. @CarlWoll Are you posting an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the last basic example for `Association` says:

*Associations can be modified by resetting values:*

```
assoc=<|a->x,b->y,c->z|>
```

> <|a -> x, b -> y, c -> z|>

```
assoc[b]=w
```

> w

```
assoc
```

> <|a -> x, b -> w, c -> z|>

So, you can just set the values directly using:

```
dataset = <|
    2 -> <|3 -> 3, 5 -> 4|>,
    4 -> <|5 -> 15|>,
    5 -> <|1 -> 41, 2 -> 4,  3 -> 10, 4 -> 11|>
|>;
dataset[4, 5] = {5, 6};

dataset
```

> <|2 -> <|3 -> 3, 5 -> 4|>, 4 -> <|5 -> {5, 6}|>, 
>    5 -> <|1 -> 41, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 10, 4 -> 11|>|>

Notice that 4, 5 has been reset from `15` to `{5, 6}`.